# Editing a aab file?

Tags: java, android-studio

I created an app using Android Studio. I factory reset my computer and forgot to save the app to a different location.

I happened to have sent an "app-debug.aab" to someone and was able to download it, looking through it, it seems to have all of the components but I don't know how to open it/access it to begin editing. Is there a way to convert an aab file back into an editable project in Android Studio?

Comment: That's a signed bundle -- there's no source code to edit. The closest you can come is to generate an APK from the bundle, decompile the APK and fix the source by hand, which is potentially a fate worse than starting over.

Comment: Damn, yeah I thought that might have been the case. It was a simple app, I'll just have to rebuild it :(

Comment: If it's simple, consisting of just a few classes, decompiling might be in order. Resolving all the new names that the decompiler gives your variables, classes, etc. is the main headache, but if the app isn't too complex and the decompiler is good, you could get your source back and learn something in the process. You also want to look into solutions like GitHub or DropBox, which back up to the cloud automatically.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I will look into your suggestions :)